# Is the order of these JS scripts correct?

Tags: javascript

These scripts won't load on first page load, but when I hit refresh they load up correctly. This is the latest version of Chrome with all extensions disabled.

```
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/select2/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery.maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery-autosize/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-ui/ui/mouse.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery-ui/ui/draggable.js"></script>

    <!-- page application js -->
    <script src="/js/forms-wizard.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/component-calendar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where in the page are these placed? In the <head>?

Comment: We have no idea... Are they?

Comment: You're using jquery ui's draggable but I don't see jquery-ui included. EDIT: I don't even see jquery. What does the console say?

Comment: @JonasGrumann, they are placed at the very end of the page.

Comment: You've shown your code, but not the errors. It's awfully hard to debug without knowing what's wrong.

Comment: @ssube, there are no errors. The page scripts simply don't load up unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Look at my answer, I just amended it with a bit more information about the log and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome press `F12` and click `console`. This is the error log.

Any error (such as loading a *.js file with broken references to another *.js file) will be shown here.

You can also print to this log with `console.log("hello");` and somesuch.

If there are no errors during the page load everything is in order. Otherwise, it will tell you in which file a reference is broken.

Move the file with the error below one step and then press `F5` to refresh the page. A new reference error may appear. Continue moving those files below until it loads correctly.

If you can make out more from the error (such as `autosize does not exist`) you may gain insight in which file is referenced (the one defining `autosize` in this example) and so fix the order faster than just moving files up/down.

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer I was looking for.